# Find the highest, second highest, and lowest of three random generated numbers without using conditional statements

Tags: java, algorithm, max, min

As a 1st year college IT student, I have a Java assignment where I must display three random generated numbers and order them highest, second highest, lowest. The challenge given by our professor is to not use any conditional statements or arrays.

Here is the code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat dcf = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int high, low, totnum;
    double NumAvr;
    
    high = 100;
    low = 1; 
     
    int a = (int)(Math.random()*(high-low+1)+low);  
    int b = (int)(Math.random()*(high-low+1)+low);  
    int c = (int)(Math.random()*(high-low+1)+low);   
    
    totnum = a + b + c;
    NumAvr = totnum / 3;
    
    System.out.println("The random grades are: "+a+", "+b+", "+c);
    System.out.println("====================================================");
    System.out.println("The highest number is: "+ Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c)));
    System.out.println("The second number is: "+ Math.max(b, c));
    System.out.println("The lowest number is: "+ Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c)));
    System.out.println("The average of three numbers is: "+dcf.format(NumAvr)+"%");
     

    //MathClass.java
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I am struggling to get the "in-between" value of the highest and lowest. Is there any "in-between" variable for me to get the second highest without using any conditional statement or array?

Comment: If not consider int overflow, sum all of them, then subtract max and min.

Comment: @samabcde Three values between 75 and 100; the maximum sum would be 300. Well below int overflow.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, just mention for safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int max=Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
int min=Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
int inBetween=totnum - max -min:
```

Comment: My guess is that this was what the professor was after.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without any arithmetic.

```java
int maximum(int a, int b, int c) {
    return Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
}

/**
 *  There are two conditions on the middle number. 
 *  1) It must not be maximum. The three Math.min s ensure this.
 *  2) Of the numbers which are not maximum, it should be the maximum.
 */
int middle(int a, int b, int c) {
    int minAb = Math.min(a, b);
    int minBc = Math.min(b, c);
    int minAc = Math.min(a, c);
    return maximum(minAb, minBc, minAc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `streams` for the second you can do:

```
int second = IntStream.of(a, b, c).sorted().skip(1).limit(1).findAny().getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using standard `Math.min` / `Math.max` functions is that they use comparison and ternary operator [under the hood](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l1251):

```java
public static int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a >= b) ? a : b;
}
```

Thus, if the purpose of this exercise is to *completely* avoid conditional operations in broad sense, this may be implemented by *calculating* the minimal and maximal values.

For example, in C the following formula [may be used](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-maximum-number-without-using-conditional-statement-ternary-operator/) to detect the maximum number `max = (a > b) × b + (b > a) × a;` but it won't work in Java because comparison operators result in `boolean` values.

But this approach may be modified slightly to check for negative sign when calculating the difference between two numbers and converting the sign into 1 for negative difference (`a < b`) and 0 otherwise (`a >= b`) using bit-mask and shift operations:

```java
final int s = 0x80000000; // bit mask for sign
int min = (((a - b) & s) >>> 31) * a + (((b - a) & s) >>> 31) * b;
int max = (((a - b) & s) >>> 31) * b + (((b - a) & s) >>> 31) * a;
```

So, for three random input values *truly unconditional* solution to print them in sorted order may look as follows:

```java
static void minMax(int a, int b, int c) {
    final int s = 0x80000000;
    System.out.print(a + ", " + b + ", " + c + " -> ");
    int min = (((a - b) & s) >>> 31) * a + (((b - a) & s) >>> 31) * b;
    int max = (((a - b) & s) >>> 31) * b + (((b - a) & s) >>> 31) * a;
    // or int max = a + b - min;
    
    min = (((min - c) & s) >>> 31) * min + (((c - min) & s) >>> 31) * c; 
    max = (((c - max) & s) >>> 31) * max + (((max - c) & s) >>> 31) * c;
    int mid = a - min + b - max + c;
    
    System.out.println(min + ", " + mid  + ", " + max);
    System.out.println("-----");
}
```

Tests:

```java
minMax(2, 3, 1);
minMax(2, 0, 6);
minMax(4, 2, -4);
```

Output:

```
2, 3, 1 -> 1, 2, 3
-----
2, 0, 6 -> 0, 2, 6
-----
4, 2, -4 -> -4, 2, 4
-----
```

Answer (score 0):

`totnum` is `a + b + c`. Find the `min`, find the `max`. Subtract from `totnum` that is your second highest value. Also, prefer to declare your variables when you initialize them. **Don't** perform integer math to find the average. And you could use `printf` to format. Like,

```
int high = 100;
int low = 75;
int a = (int) (Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
int b = (int) (Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
int c = (int) (Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
int totnum = a + b + c;
System.out.printf("The random grades are: %d, %d, %d%n", a, b, c);
System.out.println("====================================================");
int highest = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
int smallest = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
int second = totnum - highest - smallest;
System.out.printf("The highest number is: %d%n", highest);
System.out.printf("The second number is: %d%n", second);
System.out.printf("The lowest number is: %d%n", smallest);
System.out.printf("The average of three numbers is: %.2f%%%n", totnum / 3.0);
```

Example output

```
The random grades are: 87, 93, 89
====================================================
The highest number is: 93
The second number is: 89
The lowest number is: 87
The average of three numbers is: 89.67%
```